# Create new route stack and prevent going back in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I have the following hierarchy in my .NET MAUI app:

```
1. Home
  a. Page 1
  b. Page 2
  c. Page 3
   c.1. Stats Page
2. Section B
  a. Page 4
  b. Page 5
    b.1. User Form Page
  c. Page 6
```

I define the tabbed pages in `AppShell.xaml` which include Pages 1 through 6. The route for `User Form Page` (b.1) and `Stats Page` (c.1) are registered in `AppShell.xaml.cs`.

My `AppShell` looks like this:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home">
   <Tab Title="Page 1">
      <ShellContent Route="Page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Page 2">
      <ShellContent Route="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Page 3">
      <ShellContent Route="Page3" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page3}" />
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Section B">
   <Tab Title="Page 4">
      <ShellContent Route="Page4" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page4}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Page 5">
      <ShellContent Route="Page5" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page5}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Page 6">
      <ShellContent Route="Page6" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page6}" />
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

And `User Form Page` and `Stats Page` are registered in `AppShell.xaml.cs` like this:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(UserFormPage), typeof(UserFormPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(StatsPage), typeof(StatsPage));
```

Here's my question:

User gets to `User Form Page` by going to `Page 5` first then clicking a button. Once the user fills out the form and taps submit, I want to send user to `Stats Page`. The key is that I want to create a new a stack in my route and make sure that the user cannot go back to `User Form Page` (b.1) or Page 5 by tapping/swiping back. The user should be on `Stats Page` in a fresh stack.

I tried using the following approach but after I fill out the form, I'm not getting sent anywhere. Still sitting on the `User Form Page`.

```
var route = $"///{nameof(Page3)}/{nameof(StatsPage)}";
Shell.Current.GotoAsync(route);
```

I also tried this with a double hack i.e. `//` and got the same results. Basically, I just sit on `User Form Page` after clicking submit.

Any idea how I can make this happen?

Comment: *" I'm not getting sent anywhere"* - Sounds like an issue with route declarations. Show the xaml that declares both `Page 3` and `StatsPage`. Enough to see whether (a) these are both part of the Shell view hierarchy. And (b) whether you declare an explicit route in xaml, or allow maui to assign default route names. If Stats Page *is* part of xaml Shell view hierarchy, then you should **not** also declare a route to it in `App.xaml.cs`. Does VS Output pane give a message about "ambiguous route"?

Comment: Just updated the original post that shows both `AppShell.xaml` and `AppShell.xaml.cs`

Comment: The reason why I'm including `Page3` in the route I define after user completes the form is because on the UI, users can get to `Stats Page` through `Page 3`. So, I'm really doing it for consistency sake for users. In other words, it would be natural for users to tap back while on `Stats Page` to go back to `Page 3`. Also, the `Stats Page` displays the back icon which would take users back to `Page 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a route that matches the route you go on.

Since you want StatsPage to act like it is reached via Page3, declare a route like that:

```cs
Routing.RegisterRoute($"{nameof(Page3)}/{nameof(StatsPage)}", typeof(StatsPage));
```

Then the route you show should work.